SVG Path with Rounded Ends
I'm trying to create a filled ellipse graph in React Native using react-native-svg that visually indicates a percentage. The filled part should have rounded ends, but I'm struggling to get the positioning and shape right. Here's my current code:
import React from 'react';
import {
  Svg,
  Path,
  Defs,
  LinearGradient,
  Stop,
  ClipPath,
} from 'react-native-svg';
import {colors} from '../../../constants/colors';

interface FilledEllipseGraphProps {
  percentage: number;
}

const FilledEllipseGraph: React.FC<FilledEllipseGraphProps> = ({
  percentage,
}) => {
  const normalizedPercentage = Math.max(0, Math.min(percentage, 100));
  const stopOffset = normalizedPercentage / 100;

  return (
    <Svg width="259" height="130" viewBox="0 0 259 130">
      <Defs>
        <ClipPath id="clip-path">
          <Path d="M241.629 130C251.499 130 259.626 121.962 258.274 112.185C256.759 101.239 253.852 90.5055 249.604 80.2512C243.071 64.4788 233.495 50.1477 221.424 38.0761C209.352 26.0045 195.021 16.4288 179.249 9.89566C163.477 3.36255 146.572 -7.46234e-07 129.5 0C112.428 7.46234e-07 95.5235 3.36255 79.7511 9.89566C63.9788 16.4288 49.6477 26.0045 37.5761 38.0761C25.5045 50.1477 15.9288 64.4788 9.39566 80.2512C5.14816 90.5055 2.24084 101.239 0.726457 112.185C-0.62612 121.962 7.50119 130 17.3712 130C27.2411 130 35.0713 121.929 36.9314 112.236C38.1322 105.978 39.9673 99.8439 42.4173 93.9292C47.1541 82.4933 54.0971 72.1024 62.8498 63.3498C71.6024 54.5971 81.9933 47.6542 93.4291 42.9173C104.865 38.1804 117.122 35.7423 129.5 35.7423C141.878 35.7423 154.135 38.1804 165.571 42.9173C177.007 47.6541 187.398 54.5971 196.15 63.3498C204.903 72.1024 211.846 82.4933 216.583 93.9291C219.033 99.8439 220.868 105.978 222.069 112.236C223.929 121.929 231.759 130 241.629 130Z" />
        </ClipPath>
        <LinearGradient id="gradient-fill" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
          <Stop
            offset={stopOffset}
            stopColor={colors.background.primaryBlue}
            stopOpacity="1"
          />
          <Stop
            offset={stopOffset}
            stopColor={colors.background.primaryBlue}
            stopOpacity="0.3"
          />
        </LinearGradient>
      </Defs>
      <Path
        d="M241.629 130C251.499 130 259.626 121.962 258.274 112.185C256.759 101.239 253.852 90.5055 249.604 80.2512C243.071 64.4788 233.495 50.1477 221.424 38.0761C209.352 26.0045 195.021 16.4288 179.249 9.89566C163.477 3.36255 146.572 -7.46234e-07 129.5 0C112.428 7.46234e-07 95.5235 3.36255 79.7511 9.89566C63.9788 16.4288 49.6477 26.0045 37.5761 38.0761C25.5045 50.1477 15.9288 64.4788 9.39566 80.2512C5.14816 90.5055 2.24084 101.239 0.726457 112.185C-0.62612 121.962 7.50119 130 17.3712 130C27.2411 130 35.0713 121.929 36.9314 112.236C38.1322 105.978 39.9673 99.8439 42.4173 93.9292C47.1541 82.4933 54.0971 72.1024 62.8498 63.3498C71.6024 54.5971 81.9933 47.6542 93.4291 42.9173C104.865 38.1804 117.122 35.7423 129.5 35.7423C141.878 35.7423 154.135 38.1804 165.571 42.9173C177.007 47.6541 187.398 54.5971 196.15 63.3498C204.903 72.1024 211.846 82.4933 216.583 93.9291C219.033 99.8439 220.868 105.978 222.069 112.236C223.929 121.929 231.759 130 241.629 130Z"
        fill="url(#gradient-fill)"
        clipPath="url(#clip-path)"
      />
    </Svg>
  );
};

export default FilledEllipseGraph;


This is how it should look (85%):
enter image description here
And this is my current result (50%):
enter image description here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linecap

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593502/svg-stroke-linecap-at-one-end-only

In order to achieve what you want to achieve you need to use line animation. Now you have a filled path. Besides you are clipping the path with itself. This article will help you understand  How SVG Line Animation Works

The path that you are using is an outline of the shape. That makes it more difficult to work with.
Use a simple path and create a stroke for the path. The attribute pathLength can be use for defining the length of the path -- here the value 100, that matches the 100%.


document.forms.form01.addEventListener('change', e => {
  document.getElementById('gauge')
    .setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', `${e.target.value} 100`);
});
<form name="form01">
  <lable>Value: <input name="blue" type="range"
    min="0" step="1" max="100" value="40" /></lable>
</form>
<svg width="300" viewBox="0 0 100 50">
  <defs>
    <path id="p1" d="M 10 40 a 41 41 0 0 1 80 0"
      fill="none" stroke-width="14" stroke-linecap="round"
      pathLength="100" />
  </defs>
  <use href="#p1" stroke="LightBlue" />
  <use id="gauge" href="#p1" stroke="CornflowerBlue"
    stroke-dasharray="40 100" />
</svg>



